# Getting CancellationException when shutting down EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper

Tags: java, unit-testing, cassandra

I'm writing a store unit test which uses cassandra-unit.

```
public class StoreTest {

  public void before() throws Exception {
    EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra();
    DataLoader dataLoader = new DataLoader("mydata", "127.0.0.1:9171");
    dataLoader.load(new ClassPathJsonDataSet("cassandra.json"));
  }

  @After
  public void after() throws Exception {
    EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.cleanEmbeddedCassandra();
  }

  @Test
  public void testSomething() {
    // test code
  }
}
```

The test runs fine, is able to connect to the in-memory cassandra instance, and return reasonable results.  However, when I shutdown cassandra, I get the following exception in the logs.

```
17:05:48.666 [StorageServiceShutdownHook] INFO  o.a.cassandra.thrift.ThriftServer - Stop listening to thrift clients
17:05:48.667 [StorageServiceShutdownHook] INFO  org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper - Announcing shutdown
17:05:48.782 [GossipTasks:1] DEBUG o.a.c.c.DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor - Task cancelled
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:250) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.extractThrowable(DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.java:230) [cassandra-all-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.logExceptionsAfterExecute(DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.java:194) [cassandra-all-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute(DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:46) [cassandra-all-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153) [na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_21]
17:05:49.667 [StorageServiceShutdownHook] INFO  o.a.cassandra.net.MessagingService - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
17:05:49.668 [ACCEPT-/27.0.0.1] INFO  o.a.cassandra.net.MessagingService - MessagingService shutting down server thread.
```

Where is this coming from and how can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a problem with the stop method.  My guess is that a worker thread for a for a part of the system that is still shutting down is getting interrupted before it is finished.  The [latest](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/cassandraunit/utils/EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java) EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper code deprecates the stopEmbeddedCassandra method with a comment that it does not fully work.

We embed cassandra in our unit tests using our own code.  We do not use the activate() method as the EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper class does but use the init() and start() methods of CassandraDaemon instead.  The stop() method then seems to work.  Cassandra does not embed perfectly as it expects to be executing under [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html).

If you aren't having any issues besides the annoying log message I would just configure logging to suppress that class.  Otherwise, try replacing the active() method call in EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper with the init()/start() methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is located in the method DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.extractThrowable. The source code is:

```
 public static Throwable extractThrowable(Runnable runnable)
{
    // Check for exceptions wrapped by FutureTask.  We do this by calling get(), which will
    // cause it to throw any saved exception.
    //
    // Complicating things, calling get() on a ScheduledFutureTask will block until the task
    // is cancelled.  Hence, the extra isDone check beforehand.
    if ((runnable instanceof Future<?>) && ((Future<?>) runnable).isDone())
    {
        try
        {
            ((Future<?>) runnable).get();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
        catch (CancellationException e)
        {
            logger.debug("Task cancelled", e);
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e)
        {
            return e.getCause();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

As one can see it logs the cancellation of the task with debug warning. What I did was changing the line `logger.debug("Task cancelled", e);` to `logger.debug("Task cancelled (see DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.extractThrowable)");`. This way the event is logged but does not pollute the log with stack traces that draw attention.